# Como fazer operações entre funções em C?

Tags: c, funções

A função `funA()` armazena um valor digitado pelo usuário. 
A função `funB()` permitirá que usuário escolha uma opção.
Minha dificuldade está na terceira função: Preciso criar uma função que multiplique o valor armazenado na primeira função pelo valor gerado pelo escolha do usuário. Não sei como chamar essas funções dentro da função C e utilizar os valores armazenados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funA(){

    int numA;
    scanf("%d", &numA);
}


void funB(){
    int numB;
    float x;

    printf("Escolha um valor:\n");
    printf("1 - Alto\n");
    printf("2 - Medio\n");
    printf("3 - Baixo\n");

    scanf("%d", &numB);

    if(numB == 1){x = 100;}
    if(numB == 2){x = 50;}
    if(numB == 3){x = 10;}

}
void funC(){
//?????
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem duas funções, `funcA()` e `funcB()` independentes, tudo o que ocorre dentro delas deixa de existir quando terminam de ser executadas. Você pode fazer duas coisas:

1) Fazê-las retornar algo usando `return` (consquentemente elas não podem ser  `void`)

Ex.:

```
int funA(){
    int numA;
    scanf("%d", &numA);
    return numA;
}

float funB(){
    int numB;
    float x;

    printf("Escolha um valor:\n");
    printf("1 - Alto\n");
    printf("2 - Medio\n");
    printf("3 - Baixo\n");

    scanf("%d", &numB);

    if(numB == 1){x = 100;}
    if(numB == 2){x = 50;}
    if(numB == 3){x = 10;}

    return x;
}

void funC(){
    int a = funcA();
    float b = funcB();
    float c = a + b;
    printf("Resultado: %.2f", c);
}
```

2) Enviando como parâmetro para as duas o ponteiro para variáveis criadas na `funcC()`, ou variáveis globais, caso você tenha. Para isso, estude ponteiros e passagem de parâmetros por valor e por referência.

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

As variáveis em questão existem apenas dentro das respectivas funções, são variáveis locais, não sendo possível manipulá-las de fora das funções. Para resolver o seu problema existem duas alternativas.

**1. Declare as variáveis como globais:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int numA;
    float x;

    void funA(){

        scanf("%d", &numA);
    }


    void funB(){

        printf("Escolha um valor:\n");
        printf("1 - Alto\n");
        printf("2 - Medio\n");
        printf("3 - Baixo\n");

        scanf("%d", &numB);

        if(numB == 1){x = 100;}
        if(numB == 2){x = 50;}
        if(numB == 3){x = 10;}

    }

    void funC(){

        printf("%f", x * numA);
    }
```

**2. Ou então mude o tipo do retorno das funções e manipule-os:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int funA(){
    int numA;

    scanf("%d", &numA);
    return numA;
}


float funB(){
    int numB;
    float x;

    printf("Escolha um valor:\n");
    printf("1 - Alto\n");
    printf("2 - Medio\n");
    printf("3 - Baixo\n");

    scanf("%d", &numB);

    if(numB == 1){x = 100;}
    if(numB == 2){x = 50;}
    if(numB == 3){x = 10;}
    return x;

}
void funC(){
    printf("%f", funA() * funB());
}
```